# Cordova 3.6.3) Notification plugin not working

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to get the notification plugin working for cordova 3.6.3.
The file plugin is working fine, but I'm having trouble getting the notification plugin to even load.

Here's my debug output from xcode:

```
2014-10-14 01:10:11.297 RedJami[1773:451823] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.3 is starting.
2014-10-14 01:10:11.299 RedJami[1773:451823] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-10-14 01:10:11.308 RedJami[1773:451823] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-10-14 01:10:11.313 RedJami[1773:451823] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

2014-10-14 01:10:11.603 RedJami[1773:451823] [CDVTimer][file] 83.754957ms
2014-10-14 01:10:11.603 RedJami[1773:451823] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 84.383011ms
2014-10-14 01:10:12.234 RedJami[1773:451823] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-10-14 01:10:13.746 RedJami[1773:451823] Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/459BF930-2F5F-4973-898E-47A104862A93/RedJami.app/www/index.html
```

According to the xcode debug output, it seems that the notification plugin isn't even getting loaded.

Does anyone know what's happening?

If I type `cordova plugin ls` in the command line, it shows that I have the notification plugin installed (org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.10 "Notification")

I've tried following this thread: [Cordova notification plugin failed installation (Cordova 3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915117/cordova-notification-plugin-failed-installation-cordova-3-6), but I haven't been able to see any results (I can confirm though that CDVNotification.m wasn't in my build phase, and hence I tried adding it in myself)

Comment: How did you add the plugin? (before you tried to do it manually)

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I added the plugins through `cordova plugin add (org.apache.cordova.dialogs)`

Comment: Ok, did you run `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` after that?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes, I've tried both. Hence why my file plugin's working.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to do the following

1. cordova platform rm ios
2. make sure all plugins are installed
3. cordova platform add ios
4. cordova build ios

The only way I could get this to work, I found, was to make sure that I had all the plugins installed prehand, before adding the ios platform. `cordova platform add ios` would then install each plugin without problem.

Basically, each time I need a new plugin, I'll have to remove the current ios platform, then recreate it after the plugin's been installed..

(cordova 3.6.3)